# Why does the following method for finding the intersection of two vectors spaces fail?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, fake-proofs

I'm just curious as to why the following procedure for finding the intersection of two vector spaces doesn't work:

---

Say I'm asked to find the intersection of the vector spaces $V=\langle(1, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1)\rangle$ & $W=\langle (1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1)\rangle$.

A vector $v$ belongs to $V\cap W$ if and only if it can be expressed as both

$\alpha \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}+\beta\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\mu\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 1\\ 0\end{pmatrix}+\nu\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ for some $\alpha, \beta, \mu, \nu\in \mathbb{R}$. Thus we try to solve

$$\alpha \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}+\beta\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0\\ 1\end{pmatrix}=\mu\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 1\\ 0\end{pmatrix}+\nu\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$, or

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & -1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\alpha \\ \beta \\ \mu \\ \nu \end{pmatrix}=0$$

Since applying elementary row operations corresponds with multiplying on the left by elementary matrices, such operations preserve the solutions $(\alpha, \beta, \mu, \nu)$ of the equation above. Using elementary row operations I end up getting

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\alpha \\ \beta \\ \mu \\ \nu \end{pmatrix}=0$$

for which $(\alpha, \beta, \mu, \nu)$ is a solution precisely when $\alpha = \nu, \beta = -\nu, \mu=0$. But letting $\mu=0$ & $\nu=1$ we get

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0\\ 1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$

which is false.

Comment: When you typed *interception*, did you mean *intersection*?

Comment: I haven't checked myself but it sounds like you just made a mistake somewhere in your elementary row operations.

Comment: Maybe that's it? Would be funny because I've tried this with so many different vector spaces and haven't been able to get a correct result once.

Comment: https://www.symbolab.com/solver/matrix-row-echelon-calculator/row%20echelon%20%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7D1%261%26-1%260%5C%5C%201%260%26-1%26-1%5C%5C%201%261%260%26-1%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D Carry on from here, should get $-2$ at the end of first row and $-1$ at the end of last row.

Comment: Another way to see there was an error in the row-reduction: the first and third rows in the original matrix tell you that (x+y) = mu = nu.

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake while row-reducing it. That was it. Thank you all.